# Issue adding a JWKS to panva's node oidc-provider

Tags: node.js, openid-connect, node-oidc-provider

I am trying to add a JWKS to in node oidc-provider's configuration:

```
// configuration of oidc provider
const configuration = {
    jwks: {
        keys: [process.env.JWKS_PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
}
```

I saved the JSKW_PRIVATE_KEY in a .env file.

```
JWKS_PRIVATE_KEY={"kty":"RSA","n":"lxCIgFKl1Y2yN5THM9kvV7IXI ......etc}
```

But  I get the following error:

```
  throw new Error(err instanceof AssertionError ? err.message : 'keystore must be a JSON Web Key Set formatted object');
    ^

Error: keystore must be a JSON Web Key Set formatted object
```

How do i get through this error?